# Posting data with Awesomium

Tags: awesomium

I am looking to replace some browser instances in a WPF application.  Currently they are using IE which I believe is causing major memory leaks.  I have found three options: CefSharp, CefGlue and Awesomium.  The first two seem to be lower level implementations whereas Awesomium seems to be what I am looking for.

The deal breaker so far is I can't find a sane way to do a HTTP post.  I find the following answered question:

[Awesomnium Post Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341584/awesomnium-post-parameters)

This options seems insane, I have to register a single instance of a RequestInterceptor to do a post?  I am looking for another option, otherwise I think CefGlue is the next best bet.

Comment: what do you mean "do a HTTP post". you don't need an entire chromium based browser stack to make post requests.

Comment: @anthony, some of the pages that the application navigates to require post parameters to function, e.g. the security tokens, query parameters, etc.

Comment: yes, you will have to intercept requests and conditionally modify them to add post parameters. you will have to do something similar in awesomium, cefglue, and cefsharp.

why do you think this is "insane"? what do you think a sane interface would look like?

Comment: @anthony, how is that not insane?  I have to register an interceptor with a static property on a class to do something as simple as an HTTP post?  So this means I have to either have all my logic for every possible page post combo be in this one interceptor(I can only have one, right? The WebCore.ResourceInterceptor can have only one instance) or I have to do some stupid juggling of interceptors.  A saner interface would be the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752133(v=vs.85).aspx

Not the perdiest but very easy to post data, again, a very common scenario...

Comment: you should be able to add a navigate method that takes post data, stashes that data somewhere, then applies it in the request interceptor if that's what you really want. also, chromium, cefglue, and cefsharp are all open source if you want to modify their Navigate() api.